# Creating Arrays of Nested Objects using the ES-Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a Spark DataFrame of the schema:

```
 |-- ROW_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SUBJECT_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HADM_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHARTDATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHARTTIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- STORETIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CATEGORY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DESCRIPTION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CGID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ISERROR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TEXT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- annotations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- polarity: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- confidence: float (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- historyOf: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- ontologyMappings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- preferredText: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- codingScheme: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- cui: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tui: string (nullable = true)
```

I am indexing this entire structure in ElasticSearch, but neither the annotations field (Array of StructTypes), nor the ontologyMappings field are showing up as nested schemas. For example, the ontologyMappings mapping is shown below:

```
"ontologyMappings": {
                "properties": {
                  "code": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "codingScheme": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "cui": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "preferredText": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "code": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
```

Is there a way to force these to be written as nested types instead of just being objects with property fields? I would like to be able to run queries that find documents that contain an instance where code is a particular string and associated polarity is 1 (under ontologyMappings). Without nesting, this association is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PUT request defining which fields were nested was necessary. The payload is shown below.

```
"""{"mappings":{
      "data":{
         "properties":{
            "annotations":{
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{
                  "ontologyMappings":{
                     "type":"nested",
                     "properties":{
                        "code":{
                           "type":"text",
                           "fields":{
                              "keyword":{
                                 "type":"keyword"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "codingScheme":{
                           "type":"text",
                           "fields":{
                              "keyword":{
                                 "type":"keyword"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "cui":{
                           "type":"text",
                           "fields":{
                              "keyword":{
                                 "type":"keyword"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "preferredText":{
                           "type":"text",
                           "fields":{
                              "keyword":{
                                 "type":"keyword"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "tui":{
                           "type":"text",
                           "fields":{
                              "keyword":{
                                 "type":"keyword"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
    """
```